# Direct audio to HDMI on Raspberry Pi with Lubuntu 22.04 and alsa

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, raspberrypi

I set up a Pi4 a few days ago and was able to have it output sound to the first HDMI port. After an auto update, it lost this capability as the pulseaudio systemd service disappeared.

```
# systemctl status pulseaudio
Unit pulseaudio.service could not be found.
```

I was OK with this, as pulseaudio seems to be a complex solution to a simple problem. Alsa is simpler and more mature, so I ran

```
apt remove pulseaudio
```

Fine. Unfortunately, I can't seem to play audio to HDMI.

```
# aplay -l

**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: Headphones [bcm2835 Headphones], device 0: bcm2835 Headphones [bcm2835 Headphones]
  Subdevices: 8/8
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
  Subdevice #1: subdevice #1
  Subdevice #2: subdevice #2
  Subdevice #3: subdevice #3
  Subdevice #4: subdevice #4
  Subdevice #5: subdevice #5
  Subdevice #6: subdevice #6
  Subdevice #7: subdevice #7
card 1: vc4hdmi0 [vc4-hdmi-0], device 0: MAI PCM i2s-hifi-0 [MAI PCM i2s-hifi-0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: vc4hdmi1 [vc4-hdmi-1], device 0: MAI PCM i2s-hifi-0 [MAI PCM i2s-hifi-0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

I want to use hdmi0, which is listed as card1, so I populated /etc/asound.conf, which did not exist previously, with

```
defaults.pcm.card 1
defaults.ctl.card 1
```

speaker-test program produces

```
speaker-test 1.2.6

Playback device is default
Stream parameters are 48000Hz, S16_LE, 1 channels
Using 16 octaves of pink noise
ALSA lib pcm_direct.c:1206:(snd1_pcm_direct_initialize_slave) requested or auto-format is not available
ALSA lib pcm_dmix.c:1044:(snd_pcm_dmix_open) unable to initialize slave
Playback open error: -22,Invalid argument
```

The user that runs speaker-test is part of the audio group, and the same result is produced if root runs speaker-test.

I believe /boot/firmware/config.txt contains the correct lines.

```
hdmi_drive=2
hdmi_group=1
```

Just for fun, here is the output of "aplay -L"

```
null
    Discard all samples (playback) or generate zero samples (capture)
default
    Default Audio Device
sysdefault
    Default Audio Device
iec958
    IEC958 (S/PDIF) Digital Audio Output
samplerate
    Rate Converter Plugin Using Samplerate Library
speexrate
    Rate Converter Plugin Using Speex Resampler
jack
    JACK Audio Connection Kit
oss
    Open Sound System
pulse
    PulseAudio Sound Server
upmix
    Plugin for channel upmix (4,6,8)
vdownmix
    Plugin for channel downmix (stereo) with a simple spacialization
hw:CARD=Headphones,DEV=0
    bcm2835 Headphones, bcm2835 Headphones
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=Headphones,DEV=0
    bcm2835 Headphones, bcm2835 Headphones
    Hardware device with all software conversions
default:CARD=Headphones
    bcm2835 Headphones, bcm2835 Headphones
    Default Audio Device
sysdefault:CARD=Headphones
    bcm2835 Headphones, bcm2835 Headphones
    Default Audio Device
dmix:CARD=Headphones,DEV=0
    bcm2835 Headphones, bcm2835 Headphones
    Direct sample mixing device
usbstream:CARD=Headphones
    bcm2835 Headphones
    USB Stream Output
hw:CARD=vc4hdmi0,DEV=0
    vc4-hdmi-0, MAI PCM i2s-hifi-0
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=vc4hdmi0,DEV=0
    vc4-hdmi-0, MAI PCM i2s-hifi-0
    Hardware device with all software conversions
default:CARD=vc4hdmi0
    vc4-hdmi-0, MAI PCM i2s-hifi-0
    Default Audio Device
sysdefault:CARD=vc4hdmi0
    vc4-hdmi-0, MAI PCM i2s-hifi-0
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=vc4hdmi0,DEV=0
    vc4-hdmi-0, MAI PCM i2s-hifi-0
    Front output / input
iec958:CARD=vc4hdmi0,DEV=0
    vc4-hdmi-0, MAI PCM i2s-hifi-0
    IEC958 (S/PDIF) Digital Audio Output
dmix:CARD=vc4hdmi0,DEV=0
    vc4-hdmi-0, MAI PCM i2s-hifi-0
    Direct sample mixing device
usbstream:CARD=vc4hdmi0
    vc4-hdmi-0
    USB Stream Output
hw:CARD=vc4hdmi1,DEV=0
    vc4-hdmi-1, MAI PCM i2s-hifi-0
    Direct hardware device without any conversions
plughw:CARD=vc4hdmi1,DEV=0
    vc4-hdmi-1, MAI PCM i2s-hifi-0
    Hardware device with all software conversions
default:CARD=vc4hdmi1
    vc4-hdmi-1, MAI PCM i2s-hifi-0
    Default Audio Device
sysdefault:CARD=vc4hdmi1
    vc4-hdmi-1, MAI PCM i2s-hifi-0
    Default Audio Device
front:CARD=vc4hdmi1,DEV=0
    vc4-hdmi-1, MAI PCM i2s-hifi-0
    Front output / input
iec958:CARD=vc4hdmi1,DEV=0
    vc4-hdmi-1, MAI PCM i2s-hifi-0
    IEC958 (S/PDIF) Digital Audio Output
dmix:CARD=vc4hdmi1,DEV=0
    vc4-hdmi-1, MAI PCM i2s-hifi-0
    Direct sample mixing device
usbstream:CARD=vc4hdmi1
    vc4-hdmi-1
    USB Stream Output
```

Any idea how I can get this pi to send sound to hdmi0?

Note: raspi-config ->system options->audio shows the headphones as the only audio device. There are no options for hdmi0 or hdmi1.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem. The file /usr/share/alsa/cards/vc4-hdmi.conf that is currently being distributed with Alsa v1.2.6 on Ubuntu 22.04.3 is incorrect.

The aforementioned file should contain the following:

```
#
# Configuration for the VC4-HDMI sound card using software IEC958
# subframe conversion
#

<confdir:pcm/hdmi.conf>
vc4-hdmi.pcm.hdmi.0 {
        @args [ CARD AES0 AES1 AES2 AES3 ]
        @args.CARD {
                type string
        }
        @args.AES0 {
                type integer
        }
        @args.AES1 {
                type integer
        }
        @args.AES2 {
                type integer
        }
        @args.AES3 {
                type integer
        }
        type iec958
        slave {
                format IEC958_SUBFRAME_LE
                pcm {
                        type hooks
                        slave.pcm {
                                type hw
                                card $CARD
                                device 0
                        }
                        hooks.0 {
                                type ctl_elems
                                hook_args [
                                {
                                        name "IEC958 Playback Default"
                                        interface PCM
                                        optional true
                                        lock true
                                        preserve true
                                        value [ $AES0 $AES1 $AES2 $AES3 ]
                                }
                                ]
                        }
                }
        }
        status [ $AES0 $AES1 $AES2 $AES3 ]
}

# default with plug
vc4-hdmi.pcm.default {
        @args [ CARD ]
        @args.CARD {
                type string
        }
        type plug
        slave.pcm {
                type softvol
                slave.pcm {
                        @func concat
                        strings [ "hdmi:" $CARD ]
                }
                control {
                        name "PCM Playback Volume"
                        card $CARD
                }
        }
}
```

This is described on the [RPi forums](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=330349). Although the poster says that this solution does not work for them, it does work for me.